# Can't target last of type in React Styled Component input

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Hi using Styled components with React - building a split date input for day/month/year - the only change I want to make is that the width of the year input is double the length of the other two inputs, I've tried using `:nth` `last-of-type` etc but to no avail, I have a suspicion it is because how I'm rendering the inputs as components? Can anyone advise of a nice workaround?

Code:

```
const StyledInput = styled.input`

  display: block;

  height: 48px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
`;

  return (
    <StyledInputGroup>
      <label>
      <span>Day</span>
      <StyledInput
        type="text"
        maxLength="2"
        label="Day"
        value={day}
        onChange={(e) => setDay(e.target.value)}
      />
      </label>
      <label>
      <span>Month</span>
      <StyledInput
        type="text"
        maxLength="2"
        label="Month"
        value={month}
        onChange={(e) => setMonth(e.target.value)}
      />
      </label>
      <label>
      <span>Year</span>
      <StyledInput
        type="text"
        maxLength="4"
        value={year}
        onChange={(e) => setYear(e.target.value)}
      />
      </label>
    </StyledInputGroup>
  );
```

Simplified codepen:
https://jsfiddle.net/4xzn8a5q/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last-child` is not working like you are expecting.
It is searching for labels and not inputs.
If you want to use this selector, try to focus on `label` and then set the width of the input inside that `label`.

So you need to first find the last `label` child and then apply the double width inside the `input` field of that `label`.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp62fsgb/13/)

Answer (score 0):

I would add styling to the `StyledInputGroup` component to get this done. Something like this should do the trick:

```
const StyledInputGroup = styled.div`
  label:last-child input {
    width: 100px;
  }
`;
```